# Launch salesforce1 with lightning app

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

Hi right now when Salesforce1 opens, it opens the recent item page first. How do I make it open my custom lightning app when Salesforce1 launches? Is that possible? I see start url and mobile start url in the connected app for Salesforce1. Is that where I should enter lightning app url?

Comment: Is your component listed at the top of the Navigation Menu Items list on the Mobile Navigation page?  The first item in the Selected list becomes your Salesforce1 landing page. See step 2c on [this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm).

Comment: No. I think I can do that though. Wonder if the start url and mobile start url can be used also though.